# Skip a part of a for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, goto

I'm trying to create a batch script that will record the locations of found instances of `hello.txt`. The problem is that I *could* have one copy of `hello.txt` in both `%workingroot%` and/or `%startingloc%`.

In the script, I tried to make it check whether or not it was in `%workingroot%` or `%startingloc%`. But when it is triggered and goes to the label `:skip`, it appears to forget that it was still in a `for` loop and just continues on down the script.

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b /a-d "%searchloc%\hello.txt"') do (
if "%%f"=="%workingroot%" goto skip
if "%%f"=="%startingloc%" goto skip
echo Instance found.
set /a foundd=!foundd!+1
echo %%f>> "%templl%\wefound.txt"
:skip
)
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You do not want to count instances of hello.txt on `%workingroot%` nor in `%startingloc%` ?

Comment: Nope, I already know they exist.

Comment: could it be that `%%f` never actually has the `%workingroot%` nor `%startingpoint%` values ? have you echo `%%f` t ?

Comment: You may have a point - I'll go check that now.

Comment: It turns out they were not the same. I have corrected it and it works perfectly now. Thanks! :)

Comment: You should add your own answer because the voted answer now is not an answer actually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b /a-d "%searchloc%\hello.txt"') do (
 if not "%%f"=="%workingroot%" if not "%%f"=="%startingloc%" (
  echo Instance found.
  set /a foundd=!foundd!+1
  echo %%f>> "%templl%\wefound.txt"
 )
)
```

should work for you.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but i am still getting the locations of `%workingroot%` and `%startingloc%` in `wefound.txt`...

Comment: `if not "%%~dpf"=="%workingroot%" if not "%%~dpf"=="%startingloc%" (` <--- this may work - if you don;t have trailing \ on the paths.

Comment: The exclusion is literal - the values in the exclude-me variables must exacly match the value in `%%f`. You haven;t shown what the contents of those variables actually is - it may be the entire filename (which then matches `%%f`) or it may be just a pathname in which case you should match `%%~dpf` as foxidrive has advised. Note that even here, it's case-sensitive (can alter that by adding the `/i` switch to `if`) and `%%~dpf` will include a terminal `\`. Really, without knowing exactly what the contents of your variables are, there is a plethora of possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, it turned out `%%f` didn't match `%workingroot%` and `%startingloc%`. I fixed it and its working well now. Thanks for your help :)